# CTE creating recursive dynamic rows and columns based on input

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, dynamic-pivot

I am creating dynamic rows and columns based on input from user. The output is similar to this.

[image]

So far I could able to compute only one column using CTE.

```
    DECLARE @ROWStart INT = 1
DECLARE @NOOFROWS INT = 5
DECLARE @NOOFOLUMNS INT = 5
DECLARE @RACK NVARCHAR(10) = 'TAB-'
;WITH   cte
AS     (SELECT @ROWStart AS n, 1 AS col,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@RACK + 'R1C1') AS RW -- anchor member
        UNION ALL
        SELECT n + 1,cte.col, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@RACK + 'R' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),n+1) + 'C' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),col))  -- recursive member
        FROM   cte
        WHERE  n < @NOOFROWS -- terminator
       )
SELECT cte.RW
FROM   cte;
```

How to create subsequent columns?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to create columns dynamically. So, your best bet is to use dynamic sql, which will make your work easier.

Comment: How are you going to make use of this result set ? I don't see a point of doing this in database, if you are going to return rows & columns of `TAB-R?C?` to the client. It will be much easier to do it in your client application. Unless there are more to the requirement that we are not aware off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @RowsLimit INT
       ,@columnsLimit INT;

SELECT @RowsLimit = 5
      ,@columnsLimit = 7;

DECLARE @DynammicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@DynamicPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@DynamicPIVOTResultsColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #Rows
(
    [value] INT
);

CREATE TABLE #Colmuns
(
    [RowID] INT
   ,[value] INT
);

INSERT INTO #Rows ([value])
SELECT TOP (@RowsLimit) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.[number])
FROM [master]..[spt_values] t1 
CROSS JOIN [master]..[spt_values] t2

INSERT INTO #Colmuns ([RowID], [value])
SELECT TOP (@columnsLimit)  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.[number]) 
                           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.[number])
FROM [master]..[spt_values] t1 
CROSS JOIN [master]..[spt_values] t2

SET @DynamicPIVOTResultsColumns = STUFF
                          (
                                (
                                SELECT ',REPLACE(''TAB-R#C' + CAST([value] AS VARCHAR(12)) + ''', ''#'', [value])'
                                FROM #Colmuns
                                GROUP BY [value]
                                FOR XML PATH('') ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                                ,1
                                ,1
                                ,''
                          );

SET @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STUFF
                          (
                                (
                                SELECT ',[' + CAST([value] AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']'
                                FROM #Colmuns
                                GROUP BY [value]
                                FOR XML PATH('') ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                                ,1
                                ,1
                                ,''
                          );


SET @DynammicTSQLStatement = N'
SELECT '+ @DynamicPIVOTResultsColumns +'
FROM #Rows
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #Colmuns
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([value]) FOR [RowID] IN (' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + ')
    ) PVT
) DS';


EXEC sp_executesql @DynammicTSQLStatement;


DROP TABLE #Rows;
DROP TABLE #Colmuns;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
DECLARE
    @NOofColumns INT = 5,
    @NoOfRows INT = 5

DECLARE
    @ColumnNames VARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @Initial VARCHAR(16)= 'TAB-',
    @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

;WITH Nums
AS
(
    SELECT 
        1 AS Number

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        Number + 1
    FROM
        Nums
    WHERE 
        Number < 99
)
SELECT * INTO #Number FROM Nums

SELECT TOP(@NOofColumns) * INTO #ColumnNumber FROM #Number

SELECT TOP(@NoOfRows) * INTO #RowNumbers FROM #Number

SELECT 
    ISNULL('['+@Initial + 'R'+XX.ColumnNo+'C'+XX.RowNo+']','') AS Name,
    ColumnNo,
    RowNo
INTO 
    #Final
FROM
(
SELECT
    CAST(AA.Number AS VARCHAR(8)) AS ColumnNo,
    CAST(BB.Number AS VARCHAR(8)) AS RowNo
FROM
    #ColumnNumber AA
CROSS JOIN
    #RowNumbers BB
)XX

SELECT 
    @ColumnNames = ISNULL(@ColumnNames+',' ,'') + '['+CAST(AA.Number AS VARCHAR(16))+']'
FROM
    #RowNumbers AA
ORDER BY
    AA.Number

SELECT
    @SQL = @SQL + '
SELECT 
    '+@ColumnNames+'
FROM
(
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    #Final AA
)XX
PIVOT
(
    MAX(NAME) FOR ROWNO in ('+@ColumnNames+')
)yy'

EXEC(@SQL)

DROP TABLE #Number
DROP TABLE #ColumnNumber
DROP TABLE #RowNumbers
DROP TABLE #Final
```